# Launching a process from inside a controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to start a process from inside a controller. 
I've tried the usual

```
pid = fork do
 code
end

Process.detach(pid)
```

But nothing is happening. When I try with eval(code) in the fork block the code runs but it's the actual rails server/puma running it. This means that when I kill the process I also shut down the whole server.

I had some code before that I lost that worked and I'm nearly sure it used exec or eval or something like this that created a process(and therefore returned a pid to be able to kill it later) and I remember checking with ps that it was run by something of rails but not the actual whole server.

Why isn't the fork do block enough for it to work? What's the way to do it?
And, for non-testing purposes and actual implementation, how can I make it run totally independent from the rails server?

Comment: Rails provides a built-in framework for running background tasks: [`ActiveJob`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html). Use that, unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: I do not want jobs sorry.

Comment: What you are describing - "forking the process", and running some asynchronous task, **is** a background job. What makes you say this is unsuitable?

Comment: Jobs are not suited because they are not for the sort of task my application needs.

Comment: .....And what sort of task is it that your application needs? A "job" is a very generic concept; it can be *any* asynchronous task. This question looks almost certainly like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/369864) to me: You're insisting on getting help with a chosen solution, rather than explaining the original problem to be solved.

Comment: I've looked extensively into jobs. 

I do not need a polling mechanism as my tasks are to be done immediately. I do not need my taks to be done in the near future/future.

My tasks can run for days on end, weeks even. 

My tasks need to be able to be stopped at any time. Started/stopped. 

I need processes. 

I had a working system one liner for testing purposes and I can't seem to find my way back to it. And I dont understand why my code doesn't work here.

Comment: I tested [this](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process.html#method-c-detach) example un my controller ant it worked. In terminal I got `Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  PID STAT
80352 Z+`. Also this worked:     `@p1 = fork { puts '---'*100}
    Process.detach(@p1)`

Comment: @sokse (1) What does polling have to do with this? Neither of us mentioned that. (2) Your tasks are to be done immediately ... not in the future/near future ... and can run for days on end. OK, so use `#perform_now` from `ActiveJob`! This will start the task immediately, and it can run for as long as you like. (3) Stopping tasks -- This can be done many ways; the implementation depends on what your task is actually doing, but since you never showed this in your question I cannot advise much further. For example, if you're using `sidekiq` then you could just scale down workers on that queue.

Comment: Sorry I meant queueing instead of polling, my bad. 

Queueing implies that there's a queue, workers working on tasks one by one right? It's not done all at the same time. 

The tasks for my application need to be all done at the same time, turned on or off when the user wants. This kind of thing. 

I really looked a lot into jobs and I knew that I could make it immediate but I can't wrap around my head the fact that there's a "queue"? I really dont think it's fit for my needs. 
And I've understood that my main problem right now is that the process is run by the rails server.

Comment: @iGian thanks I've realised the process actually runs, just not by who I want it to run.

Comment: Also detached an infinite loop process. What I noticed is that I can kill the process while the rails server keeps running. If I kill the server I can not kill the process anymore by `kill -9 PID`

Comment: @sokse If you really want to run the whole task in one big process (even though it takes several days), ignoring the fact that this is probably a bad solution (see: XY problem), then you will only have one job on the "queue" and therefore there's no real need to even think of it as a "queue"! It's simply a background task. By following the approach I keep repeating, your process will be run by whatever adapter you choose - e.g. `resque`, `sidekiq` or `delayed_job` - and will not be dependant on the rails server.

Comment: And I can use this jobs with no queue system to run these taks all at the same exact time? 
So user A could run his task and user B could run his task and they'll both be executed in parallel(like processes are)? 
Or user A runs task1 and task2 in parallel for example?

Thanks a lot for the help, it sure would make stuff much easier for me if I can use jobs. I was thinking I need to have a ruby program that spawns/kills children processes and that communicates with the rails app. 
I think that can get pretty messy fast. 

Thanks a lot for your help by the way!

Comment: [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) is most definitely what you need @sokse - from your latest comment it seems you want to allow your User to start a Process that runs at any given time, concurrent with other users (to some maximum determined by your hardware/code efficiency). What I'm not sure is if you can send signals to running processes in the case you need interactivity - anyone have thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a shell command from inside your Rails controller using `exec`.

I hope you are looking for the same. The process you start on the system will be totally independent of the Rails server and will be visible under `ps` command if it is running when you hit the command.

Documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exec

Comment: I just tried doing exec eval("my code") inside the 'fork do' and it gets run by the server. 

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `exec` will execute the code on the system(your OS). Whereas `fork` will create a child thread from main Rails process. More info about `fork` here: http://www.tweetegy.com/2012/04/forking-ruby-processes-or-how-to-fork-ruby/